# How to control a BMT transaction outside of the EJB container?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, transactions

Just out of curiosity, is it possible to directly control an EJB transaction from the Web Container?

To illustrate I made this simple example initiating a `UserTransaction` in the Web Container(using a Servlet), but the transaction is not bound to the EJB Container (in this case a BMT SFSB).

Why is it? Is there a way to do it?

**Stateful Session Bean using BMT**

```
@Stateful
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.BEAN)
public class CustomerBean implements CustomerBeanLocal{

    @PersistenceContext(type=PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED)
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    public Integer createCustomer(String name) {

        Customer customer = new Customer();
        customer.setId(1);
        customer.setName(name);
        em.persist(customer);
        //em.flush();

        return customer.getId();
    }   
}
```

**UserTransaction is initiated in the Servlet, but the Session Bean doesn't persist**

The Customer is not persisted to the database.

```
public class BMTServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @EJB
    private CustomerBeanLocal customerBean;

    @Resource
    private UserTransaction userTransaction;

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        try {           

            userTransaction.begin();

            customerBean.createCustomer("Tars");       

            userTransaction.commit();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new ServletException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

If we uncomment the `em.flush();` then we get the following exception:

```
javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress
    org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.flush(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:792)
    org.jboss.ejb3.jpa.integration.JPA1EntityManagerDelegator.flush(JPA1EntityManagerDelegator.java:86)
    bean.CustomerBean.createCustomer(CustomerBean.java:25)
```

Comment: Switch your EJB `TransactionManagement` to container, then it will use transaction started in web module. BMT says that you (the bean) will be handling transaction by itself, so thats why it is not using transaction started in the web module.

Comment: @Gas We use CMT in most applications, and as you said, we also use BMT controlling the `UserTransaction` inside the EJB container. It just occurred to me this idea since we saw some old here doing it, but as we further tested it the begin/commit in the Servlets was doing no change at all. In short, it doesn't work as I demonstrated in the question's example.

Comment: Maybe we don't understand each other. I'll try to rephrase - BMT will not work in your scenario. To control transaction from servlet using UserTransaction, the bean must be CMT.

Comment: @Gas You are damn right Gas. Now that I think of my question I am feeling kinda dumb, I already used it in the past. You can post an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BMT will not work in your scenario, as BMT bean will be handling transaction by itself and will not participate in the transaction started in the web module (the container transaction). To control transaction from servlet using UserTransaction, the bean must be CMT.